# crystal Error: undefined method 'length' for Array(String)

Tags: crystal-lang

converting something from ruby to crystal

```
$ cat test.cr
puts ARGV.length
```

works in ruby, but crystal

```
$ crystal test.cr

Showing last frame. Use --error-trace for full trace.

error in line 1
Error: undefined method 'length' for Array(String)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

appears the correct method is "size".  crystal doesn't have as many aliases, to standardize.

```
$ cat test.cr
puts ARGV.size

$ crystal test.cr 1 2 3
3
```